# Magento Hide Div ID if Grand Total Less than Dollar Amount

Tags: magento, html, hide, checkout

I'm trying to hide or display a div based on the cart grand total.  For instance, if the cart grand total is less than $79, i'd like to hide the div.  I've tried using conditional statements but it's not quite working. I've tried using the below code in onepage.phtml, review.phtml (where the div is placed) and in the actual file that holds the div I'd like to hide.

```
<?php
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); 
$subtotal = round($totals["subtotal"]->getValue()); 
$grandtotal = round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue()); 
if ($grandtotal <= '79'){ ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">$('#gifterWrap').hide()</script>
   <?php
    }
?>
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

EDIT: After trying a few of the fixes below, I think the error may be in the first part of the code, where I get the totals subtotal etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
 <script language="javascript">
     grandTotal=<?php echo round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue());?>;
     alert(grandTotal); // to check if it's the right value.
     if (grandTotal<=79){
         $('#gifterWrap').css('display', 'none');
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: For some reason this caused the one step checkout to redirect to the first page of the cart at step 5 of 6 when the continue button was hit. Any ideas?

Comment: Try placing a breakpoaint in the JS using Firebug or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing '79' (string) to 79 (int)

```
<?php if(79 >= Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()): ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">$('#gifterWrap').hide()</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See

- http://amjath.com/2012/06/get-subtotal-and-grand-total-in-magento.html
- http://www.magazento.com/english/blog/cartinfomagento

Comment: I tried putting this in into the same spots as before onepage.phtml, review.phtml, and in the actual module form and still no luck.  could it be the first part is done incorrectly?

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.magazento.com/english/blog/cartinfomagento  and http://amjath.com/2012/06/get-subtotal-and-grand-total-in-magento.html